# Adding words to lstlisting for Python language

Tags: listings, color, python

I wish to add a few keywords to some python code inserted into a LaTeX document. I want to make `True` & `False` appear yellow and also some module calls such as `ttk` appear red. I have tried using the morekeywords call, however, it is not working for me. Below is my LaTeX code:

```
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttm,
otherkeywords={self},             
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
morekeywords={ttk}
emph={MyClass,__init__},          
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},

showstringspaces=false            
}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: No problem, appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
keywords=[<number>]{<list of keywords>}
```

to add another set of keywords and then

```
keywordstyle={[<number>]<style commands>},
```

to give a style for this new set.

Since I didn't have the original definitions for your colors nor of the \ttb command, in the example below I used some own settings, but you can easily use your own settings; the code was randomly taken, just for this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{bera}% optional; just for the example

\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
otherkeywords={self},             
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue!90!black},
keywords=[2]{True,False},
keywords=[3]{ttk},
keywordstyle={[2]\ttfamily\color{yellow!80!orange}},
keywordstyle={[3]\ttfamily\color{red!80!orange}},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          
emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{red!80!black},    
stringstyle=\color{green!80!black},
showstringspaces=false            
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting} 
def under_attack(col, queens):
    left = right = col
    for r, c in reversed(queens):
        left, right = left - 1, right + 1

        if c in (left, col, right):
            return True
    return False
    print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
ttk.Button(buttonframe,width = 3,
           textvariable=guivars["%s %s" %(current, item)],
           command=lambda: remoteButton(current, item))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please notice that "ttk" is being treated as a keyword with red color, as was also requested.

Comment: This is great, sorry for the lack of not mentioning the \ttb deceleration. This will help me greatly.