# How can I insert the following WinBugs code into Latex as a text format?

Tags: spacing, formatting, typewriter

How can I insert the following WinBugs code into LaTeX as a text format?

```
  model
  {
    for(i in 1:nSUB)
    {
      s[i] ~ dnorm(0,tau.precision);
    }
  }
```

I tried `\texttt{}`:

```
\texttt{model
\{   \par
  for(i in 1:nSUB)   \par
  \{   \par
    s[i] $\sim$ dnorm(0,tau.precision);  \par
  \}  \par
\}
}
```

However, it gives a error message:

> ```
> {model \{
> ! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete. ....
> ```

I tried  `\usepackage{listings}`, and used language R because there's no WinBugs language included.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]

model
{
  for(i in 1:nSUB)
  {
    s[i] ~ dnorm(0,tau.precision);
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

There's no error message, but the text still looks very strange.

Comment: `verbatim` environment is the simple approach.

Comment: HI, *strange* is a very relative concept, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @BambOo I assume that, by *strange*, the OP means non-proportional spacing.

Comment: @BambOo By strange I meant some words are bolded while some are not. I guess the bolded ones are considered as functions, but it's not consistent with WinBugs. Also, the ~ is weird looking.

Comment: @celadonz, check the `listings` ([here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings)) or `minted` packages. Both of them have great documentation. Check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106844/adding-words-to-lstlisting-for-python-language) for instance as a starting point. This will help you make your own language style.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes verbatim actually works quite well. My only complain is the ~ symbol looks strange. It's small and high. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: While there are a number of alternatives people have tried to replace the tilde (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320855/why-is-tilde-not-available-out-of-the-box-in-tex/320883#320883), that technique does not work in `verbatim`.

Comment: However, this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120797/tilde-in-verbatim may help, if you can adapt to `listings`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know WinBugs, but turns out there's a lexer for pygments. You can use the minted environment as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{winbugs}
model
{
  for(i in 1:nSUB)
  {
    s[i] ~ dnorm(0,tau.precision);
  }
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

The result looks quite reasonable although you can apply a different style if you prefer fewer or more colors. I tend to go with bw.

[image: minted]

Comment: Your results look neat! However, I cannot reproduce on my computer. I pasted your original code to a tmp.tex file. When I compile it, there's an error message saying '!Latex Error: File 'tmp.pyg' not found'. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Possibly you need to run with `--shell-escape` argument... Not sure because I haven't use it... Just check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99476/120578

Comment: Python and Pygments are prerequisites for minted, but easily installed as per section 2 of the minted manual. And you need to invoke latex with command-line option -shell-escape.

Comment: @tucuxi I see. Unfortunately this is a company machine and I don't have admin rights to install anything. Thanks though.